# class instantiation gives positional error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

i have a class definition as follows :

```
class Trade:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # lots of things
```

I am trying to instantiate one by doing :

```
trade_tmp = Trade(json.loads(trade_str))
```

My understanding was that the `**kwargs` argument would automatically pickup the generated dictionary. Am I incorrect ?

I am getting the whole `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error which I though should not apply here.

Comment: You actually need *args here not **kwargs. And just as an aside, "args" and "kwargs" are arbitrary - it's the asterisks that count.

Comment: and *args can be a dictionary as well ? I thought dict = **, not dict = *

Comment: Ah! I see.. so what you actually wanted to do is `Trade(**json.loads(trade_str))` so that it would unpack your kwargs. Right?

Comment: No I ended up following your fist advice which I think was the correct one i.e pass a dict as a simple argument instead of passing named arguments.

Comment: if you want to post an answer i'll validate it since you were first on the case

Comment: The answers here are just as good - glad to be of service :)

Comment: cool thanks. another minor annoyance is that I now have to do my_dict = args[0] because it puts it in a tuple. Any way to get it directly as a dict ?

Comment: You can always add an actual positional argument like iBug suggested instead, then you won't have to slice it. `def __init__(self, data, *args):`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189564/discussion-between-chapo-and-rgk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict returned by `json.loads` serves as **a single argument** to the function. Therefore you need another positional argument:

```
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs)
```

While you could prepend two starts before the dict to force it as keyword arguments, it's not designed for this purpose and I recommend against this:

```
# it's valid, but don't do this
Trade(**json.loads(trade_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two choices, using args or kwargs:

```
import json

class Trade1:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      print(kwargs)

class Trade2:
  def __init__(self, *args):
      print(args)

trade_str = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
trade_tmp1 = Trade1(**json.loads(trade_str))
trade_tmp2 = Trade2(json.loads(trade_str))
```